# DC motor field voltage

Tags: dc-motor

I have a DC motor with field winding rated to 180 V [like these](https://dynamo-bg.com/en/product/dc-motors-type-mp/).
Will the winding work normally when fed with rectified (diode bridge) 220V AC voltage?

I assume that rectified current will be almost constant due to field winding inductance and it is like feeding the winding with average rectified voltage, that is about 200V. Is this assumption correct?

Otherwise where I am supposed to get this 180V from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that rectified current will be almost constant due to field winding inductance and it is like feeding the winding with average rectified voltage, that is about 200V. Is this assumption correct?

Yes, that's right. When the input voltage drops, the motor field inductance will continue to drag current out of whichever rectifier diode is connected to the highest voltage. The net effect will be as if the field winding is connected to a source with a voltage of the mean DC output of the rectifier.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Do you have any idea about the 180V rating of the winding? May it be so that 180V is the minimum voltage at which nominal RPM is achieved, but higher voltages are also allowed?

Comment: @AlexVB Several things could happen at higher voltages. The windings could overheat, which is not good. The iron could saturate, which means you don't get the speed reduction you were expecting. Maybe the 180 V specification is to allow a bit of control down from the mean DC value of 216 V with 240 VAC rms, as the supply voltage could be lower, maybe down to 220 V. With a motor field winding, even thyristor chopper (like a light dimmer) control would be useable. Even without overheating the stator, the heat from excess supply voltage eats into the thermal budget for the whole motor